# Non rectangular looking boxes in CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Basically:

Is there a better way of achieving somethink like this

[image: non rectangular box]

than by doing [this](http://jsfiddle.net/psteinweber/pck24/)

```
<h2><span class="black poly1">Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br/>
<span class="black poly2">sit amed</span></h2>
```

and

```
h2 {
    line-height: 50px;
}

.black {
    color: #fff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px #C81928;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px #C81928;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 0px 0px #C81928;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 20px;
}

.poly1 {
    background: url(http://metamonks.com/meta/poly1.svg);
    background-size: cover;
}

.poly2 {
    background: url(http://metamonks.com/meta/poly2.svg);
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: 120px;
}
```

I've used SVG files, but that comes with some disadvantages:

- CSS drop shadow doesn't apply to shape but to bounding box
- not so simple to edit via code

I was thinking to placing very stretched triangles around the CSS box, but couldn't get it done properly. Should I best keep trying that (hints are very welcome!) or is there a more elegant solution for that?

Comment: `tranform:skew` would probably help here.

Comment: http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transition.html#
May be of use, find the property for one side and just play around with the sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just add the dropshadow effect to (ie inside) the SVG files themselves?

```
<svg width="369px" height="60px" viewBox="0 0 369 60" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <path d="M73,41 L77,97 L435,97 L438,49 L73,41 Z" fill="red" transform="translate(4,4)"/>
   <path d="M73,41 L77,97 L435,97 L438,49 L73,41 Z"/>
</svg>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cbx5P/2/

Comment: Yeah, that plus using inline SVG is handy indeed and tackles both of my concerns in form of bullet points. Comes with other disadvantages (e.g. caching), that's why I'll wait a bit before accepting it as _the_ solution.

Answer (score 2):

css3 3d transforms (cf. [css transform on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) and [this tutorial](http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/docs/perspective.html)) may help you. basically, you have to display two nested elements, one of which represents your shadow while the othe has your content.

define some offset for the inner element and apply a suitable 3d transform to the outer element.

basically your transform clause would look like this:

```
transform:  skewX(-5deg) skewY(-10deg) perspective( 600px ) rotateY( 45deg )   ;
```

here you have a [live example](http://collapsar.ohost.de/data/so.transform.html).

there are a couple of aspects to consider:

- you have to resort to *3d* transforms to achieve the desired distortion effect from a 2d layer perpendicular to the normal of the 2d screen.
- some of the transforms need vendor prefixes.
- the transforms might not work across all user agents. the example has been tested on chrome 33 ( chrome 33.0.1750.154 ).
- the css shadow seem to not be subjected to the perspective transforms - therefore you'd need the nested structure. on platforms where these transforms were applied to the css adornments too, you'd save the nesting of elements.

Comment: Thanks! But 3d transformations for moving around two corners of the original rectangle (note: bottom line is parallel to box layout/text) seems a bit intense. While it might be the only css-only way without SVG, I wouldn't really desire to implement it.